# List Merge columns with Null heading and Null rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list like this :

```
    BirthDate Age Unnamed:2 Gender Outstanding Waiver Coverage
 1. NAN       NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN         NaN     103
 2. 4/17/1989 NaN   58.0    F     NaN         NaN     102
 3. 4/19/1967 NaN   61.0    F     NaN         NaN     101
 4. 3/27/1980 NaN   53.0    M     NaN         NaN     103
 5. 8/20/1961 NaN   67.0    F     NaN         NaN     104
```

Required Output-

```
    BirthDate Age     Gender Outstanding Waiver Coverage
 1. NAN       NaN     NaN    NaN         NaN     103
 2. 4/17/1989 58.0    F      NaN         NaN     102
 3. 4/19/1967 61.0    F      NaN         NaN     101
 4. 3/27/1980 53.0    M      NaN         NaN     103
 5. 8/20/1961 67.0    F      NaN         NaN     104
```

Is there a way to get this output?
ex -

```
dfnew['firstcolumn'] = dfnew[dfnew.columns[1:2]].apply(lambda x:
                               ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),)
```

Also without using the Word 'Age' or index position but some logic so it merges two columns if one of them has a missing column header in case the word *Age* change to a new unknown word

Comment: What is "NaN 1"? Is it a string?

Comment: Sorry, It was typing error, i've updated it.. Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you treat column names as the first row of data. Is that intentional? What are the numbers on the left, with periods? Is that an index? In other words, please show your data frame the way it is, without any embellishments.

Comment: Yes, The numbers are the Index numbers. i've updated it now..

Answer (score 0):

Drop the old 'Age' column and rename the unnamed column into 'Age':

```
df.drop('Age', axis=1).rename({'Unnamed:2': 'Age'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!.. This should work.. But Is there a way without using the word 'Age'? Like if the column name changes from 'Age' to some other 'name' i'd still like to see the code work.